# A remote operation is taking longer than expected

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am developing an application of windows phone in VS2012 Express for windows phone. When I run the app using ctrl+F5, it gets installed properly and run fine. But when I hit F5. I get "**A remote operation is taking longer than expected**" error. I am unable to debug the app.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are using a VPN. Uninstalling Astrill VPN worked for me.