# Why could my application not be launched for debugging?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I started a completely new Windows Phone 8 application in MS VS Express for Windows Phone 8. Relatively new laptop with Windows 8 and 16GB of RAM. Hyper-V works fine. Switched-off all antivirus and firewalls. Checked configuration does deploy. I add absolutely no code and press F5. The WVGA 512MB emulator starts. Output screen gives:

```
1>  Xap packaging completed successfully
2>------ Deploy started: Project: XPhoneApp, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2> Deploying C:\...\XPhoneApp\Bin\Debug\XPhoneApp_Debug_AnyCPU.xap...
2>Connecting to Emulator WVGA 512MB...
2>The application is already installed on the device. Checking if an incremental deployment is possible...
2>Doing incremental deployment...
2>Updating information related to modified files...
2>Deployment of C:\...\XPhoneApp\XPhoneApp\Bin\Debug\XPhoneApp_Debug_AnyCPU.xap succeeded.
```

The I get an error message "The application could not be launched for debugging ...". I checked, it is indeed installed on the emulator. Anyone had this problem?

Comment: I also get the same warning noted in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745620/a-remote-operation-is-taking-longer-than-expected but I'm not sure it's the same issue.

Comment: The Windows Event Log is also notably void of any entry pertaining to this error.

Comment: Running without debugging works 100%. So I'm investigating why debugging is not able to attach.

Comment: Reinstalled Windows Phone 8 SDK. This did not solve the issue.

Comment: Ok so this bugged me too much to give up. Found something very interesting. If I switch my wifi connection off then the problem goes away. If I switch my wifi connection back on, the problem is back. It's not long now 'till I have this nailed!

Answer (score 10):

I had this issue when I was working with a real device. What worked for me is to go and manually uninstall the application I was debugging, next time I hit debug, the problem was gone. Not sure what the problem is, but maybe this uninstall thing could be helpful who are rattled with this weird error when they are hard in code :)

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue because the app was not selected for deployment in the 'Configuration Manager'.

Comment: I don't know why I don't check this setting each time. With switching between iOS, Android and Windows Phone (since I use Xamarin) it always messes around with these settings and the weird behaviour always comes out to something not being checked to build or deploy.

Answer (score 2):

I have this issue every time I have to start the emulator fresh. My simple solution is, once the emulator is open, try debugging again. So long as the emulator is still open, debugging works for me - I only have an issue when I begin debugging while the emulator is not open (i.e. when it needs to be started by VS)

Comment: Hi, so I hit F5, get the error and then (once the emulator is running) hit F5 again. On my machine it just throws the same error again. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yeah that's always worked for me, have you tried waiting a bit before doing it? Or trying it multiple times. Also the error you're getting is always explicitly "The application could not be launched for debugging..." and never "A remote operation is taking longer than expected"?

Comment: I suppose I shouldn't need to ask, because you seem to have a reasonable idea of what you're doing, but the emulator is on the start screen when you try to begin debugging, right?

Also, do you ever get the error "A specified resource (port) is already in use by another application"?

Comment: Another thing I often have to do is give focus to the emulator after it starts, before attempting to begin debug again. however I notice that your output says "The application is already installed on the device" - does that mean the emulator was already open the first time you tried this? Because my development apps are always cleared from the emulator every time I launch it

Comment: Yip on the start screen. I always get "The application could not be launched for debugging...". If I uninstall the app from the emulator and run debug again I get "A remote operation is taking longer than expected" just before it. When I go to the device it's installed and runs. I go back to start screen, hit F5, focus on the emulator and error-out.

Comment: Can you try adding some code (even just something like System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test");) and see if that works any better?

Comment: If that doesn't work either, just confirm for me that when you go to Build -> Configuration Manager... that the necessary build and deploy boxes are checked for the debug (and other) configurations

Answer (score 1):

I now and then experience this problem. I manage to solve it by deleting the Hyper-V snapshot that the emulator has created. Just start your Windows 8 Hyper-V Manager. Under "Virtual Machines" select the appropriate Windows Phone emulator instance. In the Snapshots section below you select the snapshot and in the Actions pane on the right "Delete snapshot subtree..." and get rid of that snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing had worked for me (even Windows reinstall), then I installed Update 4 for Visual Studio 2013 and it finally works!

Answer (score -1):

This is how I do it: Task Manager -> End Task: IpOverUSBSvc